# Can't get the whole barcode from BarcodeDetector

Tags: android, barcode, google-vision

I am trying to read some barcodes with google-vision api, I got it working but the BarcodeDetector doesn't read the full barcode, the max size that I got was 18 numbers(my barcode has 46~).

Here is my code:

```
private void createCameraSource() {
    BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).build();
    final CameraSource cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(1600, 1024)
            .build();

    cameraPreview.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
//...
}

barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void release() {

        }

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes= detections.getDetectedItems();
            if(barcodes.size()>0){
                String resultCode = barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;
                System.out.println(resultCode.length());

            }
        }
    });
```

Is there a way to read the full code? Maybe a library?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the barcode was poorly printed, now everything works fine.